# Newly added Raft node cannot receive proposal?

Tags: go, distributed-computing, etcd, raft

I am new to etfd/raft. I managed to make a simplest raft demo to create a cluster and make them sync proposal. The nodes in the cluster are pre-configured in peers of raft.StartNode(...)

However, when I tried to dynamically add a new node to a running cluster, although I managed to make the cluster recognized the new node, new proposals are not sent to the new node.

Here is my code: [main.go](https://github.com/Andrew-M-C/go.raftstudy/blob/master/main.go)

For short:

1. I did got entries from Ready(), and invoke ApplyConfChange() when I got raftpb.EntryConfChange type from CommittedEntries
2. Messages to each nodes are sent by channel, simulating a network RPC
3. Advance() and Step() are invoked make the state machines work.

And how I add the new node? Also for short:

1. Each node has another indivisual channel to receive conf change message
2. I send raftpb.ConfChange type to every cond change channels
3. Watching stdout, this new node is reconized by all previous nodes because they all got EntryConfChange in CommittedEntries
4. Then I make another proposal. All previous nodes received the proposal from leader node, but the new one did not.

I must had miss something or made sonething wrong, but I cannot figure out.
Anyone help? Thank you in ahead!